Que signifie "pétricière" ?
Dans le livre Inkarmations de Pierre BORDAGE, le mot "pétricières" est utilisé de la manière suivante:

Ils arrivèrent dans une cavité [...] s'élevaient d'antiques
constructions semblables [...] aux pétricières qui apparaissaient dans
les potagers du Vimana [...]

Malheureusement, une recherche google ne donne rien du tout à ce sujet. Que signifie "pétricière" ?

Inconnu au bataillon. Il y a peut-être une racine pétr- qui évoque les pierres, ou une pétrification. J'aurais pensé à des stalagmites.

Google translate gives kneaders. This probably is a wild guess based on the verb pétrir, but this gives another root that the word might be based on.

Il faudrait un peu plus de contexte pour hasarder une explication. La phrase tronquée ne permet pas vraiment de s'imaginer les lieux ;)

Avez-vous vérifié si le livre inclut un glossaire? Sinon, pouvez-vous lister toutes les occurrences du mot dans le livre, avec leur contexte immédiat?
